# Cannot render a computed property with Leaf in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

I've been trying to render a computed property using the templating engine Leaf with Vapor 3, but so far no luck. If the same property is stored, everything works fine. If I make it computed, nothing is displayed in the web page. I can understand the reasons why such solution wouldn't be working, but I'd like to know if there's any way to make it working.

**Code for the element to render**:

```
struct SocialLinkContext: Encodable, CSSStyleable {
    let hyperlinkURI: String
    let classes: [String]
    //let styleClasses: String

    init(hyperlinkURI: String, classes: [String]) {
        self.hyperlinkURI = hyperlinkURI
        self.classes = classes
        //self.styleClasses = classes.joined(separator: " ")
    }

    //Seems not to be supported by Leaf
    var styleClasses: String {
        return self.classes.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

Part of the *main_page.leaf* file:

```
...
<div class="row banner">
    <div class="banner-text">
        <h1 class="responsive-headline">Hello, world!</h1>
        <hr />
    </div>
    #embed("social_links")
</div>
...
```

The *social_links.leaf* file:

```
<ul class="social">
    #for(socialContext in socialLinks) {
        <li>
            <a href="#(socialContext.hyperlinkURI)">
                <i class="#(socialContext.styleClasses)"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The *PersonalPageContext* to be passed to the View Renderer:

```
struct PersonalWebPageContext: Encodable {
    ...
    let socialLinks: [SocialLinkContext] = [...]
    ...
}
```

And finally, the *PersonalWebPageViewController* controller:

```
private func serveWebPage(req: Request) throws -> Future<View> {
    return try req.view().render("main_page", PersonalWebPageContext())
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because Leaf uses `Codable` to convert your context type to data that Leaf can use. Now by default, `Codable` *does not* encode or decode computed properties. If you want to do that, you have to manually implement the `encode(to:)` method.

```
struct SocialLinkContext: Encodable, CSSStyleable {
    let hyperlinkURI: String
    let classes: [String]

    var styleClasses: String {
        return self.classes.joined(separator: " ")
    }

    init(hyperlinkURI: String, classes: [String]) {
        self.hyperlinkURI = hyperlinkURI
        self.classes = classes
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder)throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.hyperlinkURI, forKey: .hyperlinkURI)
        try container.encode(self.classes, forKey: .classes)
        try container.encode(self.styleClasses, forKey: .styleClasses)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case hyperlinkURI, classes, styleClasses
    }
}
```